# Select Objects from Array of Objects that match a property in MYSQL JSON

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have a table with 1 JSON type column city in a MySQL database that stores a JSON array of city objects with following structure:

```
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mumbai",            
            "countryID": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "New Delhi",            
            "countryID": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Abu Dhabi",            
            "countryID": "18"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to select objects from the cities array having `countryID = 90` but I am stuck as the array of objects is stored in a single column `city` which is preventing me from doing a `(*)` with `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(city->'$.cities', JSON_OBEJECT('countryID', '90'))`.

My query looks like this and I am not getting anywhere,

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(city, '$.cities') FROM MyTable WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(city->'$.cities', JSON_OBJECT('countryID', '90'))`

It'd be a great help if someone can point me in right direction or gimme a solution to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, there is a feature called `JSON table functions`. It converts JSON data into tabular form.Then onward you can filter the result.

The query to acheive the same is given below

```
Select  country
 FROM json_cal,
   JSON_TABLE(
     city,
    "$.cities[*]" COLUMNS(
     country JSON PATH "$",
     NESTED PATH '$.countryID' COLUMNS (countryID TEXT PATH '$')          
     )
   ) AS  jt1 
where countryID = 90;
```

The DB Fiddle can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bj8btsmL43V9UWNcFFGEg9/5)

More information on JSON Table functions can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)